# discord.py entering none instead of there @username

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is what i have right now!

```html
@client.command()
async def punch(ctx, *, response):
      response = response.replace("(", "")
      response = response.replace(")", "")

      member = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), id=response)

      embed = discord.Embed(title=f":house_with_garden: Punched: {member} :punch:", color=discord.Colour.green())
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And this is what happens: [I want it to be Sauq#(then my tag)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72Ma2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MemberConverter`

```py
@client.command()
async def punch(ctx, member: discord.Member): # By typehinting the member arg, `MemberConverter` will automatically convert it to a `discord.Member` instance
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f":house_with_garden: Punched {member} :punch:", color=discord.Colour.green()) # If you want to mention the member: `member.mention`
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```